# Is include_vars and and vars in ansible are same in their usage

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I am confused with the usage of `include_vars` and `vars`

**Example:**

```
- name: "Testing include_vars"
  include_vars: "roles/testrole/vars/test.yml"
```

The above module works, because I think `include_vars` is a pre-defined module to include variables from a given file.

The below doesn't work:

```
- name: "Defining variables locally"
  vars: 
    testvar : "value1"
```

It throws the following error:

```
ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path
```

I understand the error that there is no action. But why is there no way to specify variables locally without creating a task. Why a variable has to go with an action - what's the logic or philosophy behind it?

And while it is also possible to set_facts without another action, as `set_facts` itself is a module, there is no module to set variables locally. Why?

And if you could also add why there can't be multiple actions added on a single task like: set_facts and shell command in same task?

Answer (score 2):

*vars* is not a module. It's the declaration of [variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#using-variables). To solve the error add a module to the task. For example debug.

```
- name: "Defining variables locally"
  vars: 
    testvar: "value1"
  debug:
    var: testvar
```

You might want to review the  [Intro to Playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#basics).

To answer your question

> Why there is no module to just define variables?

Because of the flexibility. Start planning your architecture with the question "Where does the configuration data come from?". You might want to review the [Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable).

Comment: Hi..why is there no module exist just to define variables. If the scope of the defined variable is global that is to all the successive tasks, why it has to go with another module?

Comment: Scope of the variables is limited to a playbook. I've updated the answer.